# Ho do I Inject ServiceLocator into validator?

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-form, zend-inputfilter

I created a Validator for one of my form fields. To do that, I need the ServiceLocator so I would like to use a factory ...

**Edit :**

Here is my factory :

```
namespace Maintenance\Factory\Validator;

/* Zend */
use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;
/* Controller */
use Maintenance\Validator\Echeancedebut;

class EcheancedebutFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        $realServiceLocator = $serviceLocator->getServiceLocator();

        $maiContratService = $realServiceLocator->get(
            'Maintenance\Service\Model\FMaiContratService'
        );

        return new Echeancedebut($maiContratService);
    }
}
```

My Validator :

```
class Echeancedebut extends AbstractValidator
{
    const ERROR_DATEDEB = 'ERROR_DATEDEB';

    protected $maiContratService;

    protected $messageTemplates = array(
        self::ERROR_DATEDEB => "Saisie inférieure à la date de début du contrat"
    );

    public function __construct($maiContratService) {
        $this->maiContratService  = $maiContratService;
    }

    public function isValid($value){
        $this->setValue($value);
        if (!$this->validatedate($value)) {
            $this->error(self::ERROR_DATEDEB);
            return false;
        } 
        return true;
    }

    private function validatedate($date) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

### Edit :

My InputFilter:

```
public function getInputFilter()
{
    if (! $this->inputFilter) {
        $inputFilter = new InputFilter();
        $this->inputFilter = $inputFilter;
    }

    $inputFilter->add(
        array(
            'name' => 'dateDeb',
            'required' => true,
            'allow_empty' => false,
            'validators' => array(
                array(
                    'name' => 'Date',
                    'locale' => 'FR_fr',
                    'options' => array(
                        'format' => 'd/m/Y',
                    ),
                ),
                array(
                    'name' => 'Maintenance\Validator\Echeancedebut',
                    'options' => array(
                        'contratId' => $this->iMaiContratId,
                    )
                );

                return $this->inputFilter;
}
```

The problem is that it doesn't retrieve my error message, why ?

Comment: what does your factory look like ? This is where you should inject the serviceLocator if you want to. But i'm not sure this is a good idea to use the serviceLocator inside your validator.

Comment: Please show your factory. What error message do you get?

Comment: I put my Factory on Edit. So I don't understant why it tells me that the 2nd argument is missing ! "Warning: Missing argument 2 for Maintenance\Validator\Echeancedebut::__construct(), called in C:\wwwroot\intranet_new\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\ServiceManager\AbstractPluginManager.php on line 209 and defined in C:\wwwroot\intranet_new\module\Maintenance\src\Maintenance\Validator\Echeancedebut.php on line 32"

Comment: Well I deleted one of my arguments, it "works" but doesn't retrive my error messages ... i did a demo and i put on edit my validator ...

Comment: Injecting the service locator is a bad idea. The factory has access to the service locator so it can get the specific dependencies your class needs and inject them. If you inject the service locator, you now have no encapsulation, as the class can fetch anything. Define your explicit dependencies and inject those instead.

Comment: Ok I see, I just point that the Class extends another wich uses the options array, for example. Hummmm .... i will be complicated to do so ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of your factory and the name you registered in your config are not corresponding:

`Maintenance\Factory\Validator\EcheancedebutFactory` (inside your config)

`Maintenance\Factory\Validator\EcheancedebFactory` (the full class name)

`Echeancedebut` vs `Echeancedeb`.

Change that and I think it should work.

Comment: Oh ! I didn't see. Thanks. But it still not working :(

Comment: @Amelie What error message do you get now? What happened to your config. Don't remove information from your question. We won't be able to help like this.

Comment: The informations I removed aren't necessary any longer.

Comment: I don't have any error message. The script goes on but in the present case, it doesn't show the validation error message I asked (cf my validator which returns false).

Comment: @Amelie So the issue was solved and now you ask a new question?

Comment: @Amelie Normally you should accept the answer and ask a new question... To be able to help you should show your config for the InputFilter in which you use the validator and show the data that you validate.

Comment: You are passint two arguments to the constructor, via your fatory, while you actually accept one

Comment: @Wilt okay, I didn't know, I'm quite new in Stack.

Comment: @Wilt okay I edited the inputfilter call, and i validate a field that sens a date format 10/09/2015

Comment: @Amelie I formatted your code to make it readable and it seems like half of your array is missing. Please show the correct code. Make sure all is there, this is very tiring. People will stop helping you if you ask incomplete questions. Where is the data?

Comment: Wilt nice to do so but I appreciate amability. The system of code transcrition is as tiring as you pretend reading me is tiring, too, and not intuitive. I just wanted to win time (for you) to show you the points that can make issues. Would you be pleased if I paste 500 lines of code ? I don't think so. And the data is not relevant in this case. Thanks for understanding.

Comment: @Amelie I am very willing to help. Please just update your complete InputFilter config and show the data you filter... Since all other code looks fine it must be related to something which is not visible. You don't get an error but what response do you get now?

Answer (score 0):

Okay so injecting Sl in a validator is a bad idea. I will pass my options as arguments via the inputFilter, called by my controller. So the problem is solved. Thanks for your answers.

Comment: In your example you are not injecting a ServiceLocator in your validator. You use a factory to find services (dependencies) and inject those in your validator. This is totally according to ZF2 specifications.
It would be bad if your would do:  `new Echeancedebut($serviceLocator);`

Comment: I won't do new Echeancedebut($serviceLocator); I found another way. Using a factory corrupts options sending. I understood this with my issue.